# does inductance of a coil with core change with frequency?

Tags: electromagnetism

The inductance should stay the same, yet when I measure the inductance with RLC meter I find that inductance of a planar coil with a cooking pot placed on top changes drasticaly. At low frequency I get biggest inductance, but it lowers with increasing frequency.

Is this meassurement error or does increasing frequency change the behaviour of metal so it changes the inductivity of the coil?

Comment: It is unclear as to how you are changing the frequency and then measuring the inductance with you LCR meter.  In creasing the frequency would increasing the eddy currents in you pots and it would be no surprise that this is different for different pots as their resistance.resistivity would differ.  If the pots are made of iron then there would also be an increased loss due to hysteresis as the frequency increased.

Comment: My RLC meter has it's own function generator. I'm increasing frequency from 20 Hz to 200 kHz. The current is being kept at 10 mA. The measured inductance is changing for a good metal pot from 0.2 mH to 0.04 mH. I'm interested if this effect is real, or is there a mistake being made by the RLC meter in how it calculates inductance.

Comment: What happens to the inductance reading as the frequency is changed  when there is no pot?

Comment: It is decreasing to a certain frequency (depending on the coil) let's say around 100 to 500 kHz, then it starts to increase with increasing frequency. But I can only measure up to 1 MHz, and unaccurately at that. But the inductance is changing very little compared to if the pot is placed on top.

What I see is that when a pot is placed on top the inductance quickly decreases up to around 10 kHz, then it starts to decrease less and less.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your metal pot in place, you have a transformer, with the pot as a short-circuited secondary. An emf is induced around the pot, and there is an alternating current in it (mutual induction). But this alternating secondary current induces an emf in the primary coil (mutual induction again). When phases are taken into account, it turns out that the effective inductance of the primary is reduced. For details, consult a textbook or web article dealing with transformers at first year university level.

Comment: Thank you! could the difference in measured inductance be from 0.2 mH to 0.04 mH when I use 20 Hz input vs. at 200 kHz?

Comment: I agree that it's a big difference, but I'd guess the transformer effect could explain it.